# multiple onEdit trigger execution timing out

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a apps script which had three `OnEdit()` triggers, as below

```
function onEdit(e) {
  onEdit1(e); // The function for hide/unhide sheets/tabs
  onEdit2(e); // The function for hide/unhide row in ESS sheet
  onEdit3(e); // The function for hide/unhide rows in a
}

function onEdit1(e)   {

  var cp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var a = cp.getSheetByName("A");
  var b = cp.getSheetByName("B");
  var check_value = cp.getSheetByName("check sheet");

  
  var cella = check_value.getRange('C6');
    if (cella.getValue() == 'Yes')  {
      a.showSheet();
    }
    else {
      a.hideSheet();
    }

  var ç = check_value.getRange('C7');
    if (cellb.getValue() == 'Yes')  {
      b.showSheet();
    }
    else {
      b.hideSheet();
    }
  
}

function onEdit2(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var ESS = ss.getSheetByName("BBB");
    var cellx = ESS.getRange("D13");
  
    if ((cellx.getValue() == "Accept")  || ((cellx.getValue() == ""))){
      ESS.hideRows(15);
    }
    else {
      ESS.showRows(15);
    }

}


function onEdit3(e) {
  var sd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var info = sd.getSheetByName("Z");
    var a = sd.getSheetByName("A");

    var check = info.getRange("J9");

    if (check.getValues()== "Direct"){
      a.hideRows(37,8);
  
    }
    else{
      if((check.getValues()== "Indirect") || (check.getValues()== "")){
        a.showRows(37,8);      
  
}
```

There are no errors and the execution completes without any errors but upon changing/editing the values the hiding/unhiding for the sheet and rows does not happen.

I did try to look at other posts on the timing out of onEdit() function, but am unable to understand what changes to make in my code.

Also when I look at the `Executions` I get `Function- onEdit(), Type- Simple Trigger, Status- Timed Out`

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var a = e.source.getSheetByName("A");
  var b = e.source.getSheetByName("B");
  var csh = e.source.getSheetByName("check sheet");
  var [cella, cellb] = csh.getRange("C6:C7").getValues().flat();
  if (cella == 'Yes') { a.showSheet(); } else { a.hideSheet(); }
  if (cellb == 'Yes') { b.showSheet(); } else { b.hideSheet(); }
  var esh = e.source.getSheetByName("BBB");
  var cellx = esh.getRange("D13").getValue();
  if ((cellx == "Accept") || ((cellx == ""))) { esh.hideRows(15); } else { esh.showRows(15); }
  var shz = e.source.getSheetByName("Z");
  var sha = e.source.getSheetByName("A");
  var check = shz.getRange("J9").getValue();
  if (check == "Direct") { sha.hideRows(37, 8); } else {
    if ((check == "Indirect") || (check == "")) {
      sha.showRows(37, 8);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @Cooper.  Ia m getting after saving and running ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined```. should I replace  ```e.source by SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()``` I am sorry my little understanding, I am just starting out to learn apps script

Comment: Also. I am getting ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'showSheet' of null``` at the line ```if (cella == 'Yes') { a.showSheet(); } else { a.hideSheet(); }```.  tried to comment out the first function and when executed, there is no error for ```if ((cellx == "Accept") || ((cellx == ""))) { esh.hideRows(15); } else { esh.showRows(15); }
  var shz = e.source.getSheetByName("Z");``` but again error at  ```if (check == "Direct") { sha.hideRows(37, 8); } ``` as```TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideRows' of null```

Comment: You cannot run this function from a menu or script editor. It requires the event object of the onEdit trigger

Answer (score 0):

You should check your code for typos.

cellb is not defined

```
if (cellb.getValue() == 'Yes')  {
```

Change getValues() to getValue().  getValues() returns an array not a value.

```
if (check.getValues()== "Direct"){

if((check.getValues()== "Indirect") || (check.getValues()== "")){
```

To:

```
if (check.getValue()== "Direct"){

if((check.getValue()== "Indirect") || (check.getValue()== "")){
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check thoroughly